# correct using NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller, uitableview, nsurlconnection

I'm working on app, which sends and receives JSON data using NSURLConnection, but I have this connection and its delagate methods inside viewcontroller, and that's not correct for MVC I guess. I've wanted separated class for whole connection, but there was problem that I couldn't detect then in viewcontroller, when the connection finished loading, so I couldn't get received data. What is the correct way to do this ?

However, this hole (non MVC) NSURLConnection inside viewcontrollers works fine for my app, except one case - when I need to use tableview, which is part of viewcontroller - which is also datasource and delegate for this tableview. It seems like tableview is trying to create cells, before connection finished loading, which is little bit weird I think, because in method tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: I already have data I need, and I thought that this method is called before I'm configuring cell in tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath: ...but I'm wrong probably. Can somebody explain me what's going on here and how to solve this ? (also the first part with correct using of MVC with NSURLConnection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a delegate protocol for your JSON client class, e.g.:

```
@protocol JSONClientDelegate <NSObject>
...
- (void) connectionFinishedLoading;
...
@end

@interface JSONClient
{
    id<JSONCLientDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<JSONClientDelegate> delegate;
-(void) getJSON;
@end

@implementation JSONClient

- (void) getJSON
{
    ...
    [NSURLConenction connectonWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    ...
}

- connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*) connection
{
    [delegate connectionFinishedLoading];
}

@end
```

Then, have your viewcontroller implement the delegate protocol:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <JSONClientDelegate>
...
- (void) doFoo;
...
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void) doFoo
{
    ...
    JSONClient* client = [JSONClient new];
    client.delegate = self;

    [client getJSON];
    ...
}

- (void) connectionFinishedLoading
{
    // Connection finished - do things here.
}

@end
```

Note that this is an extremely abbreviated example - I've cut a few corners to save some space. I trust you can read between the lines and fill in the gaps - if not (i.e. my example is unclear), let me know and I'll elaborate further.

Answer (score 0):

As to the first part of the question, you could get a more MVC design if you:

1. implement your JSON/NSURLConnection stuff in model classes, which also implement the delegate protocol and do all necessary processing of the response;
2. when the response is processed, the view controller is sent a message; you could either define a custom delegate for this (i.e., a specific message you send to the controller that is defined in an ad-hoc protocol), or simply use notifications, which allows for more decoupling and is possibly easier to implement (but more expensive at runtime);
3. the view controller responsibility, upon reception of that message, is making so that the UI is updated to reflect the new data.

As to the second part of your question, it is normal that the table view creates the cells as soon as it has to redraw itself, i.e., before the data is there (since this takes time).

What you need to do is letting the table draw itself empty (possibly showing a "loading" bit of UI) and calling `reloadData` on the table when the view controller is notified that the data has been received and processed.

This will be pretty natural if you follow the guidelines above for making your design more decoupled according to MVC.

EDIT: about your last question:

I don't know how and where you create the `myArray` object, but, as a general rule, I would expect it to be an ivar of your data source object (if I am not understanding things incorrectly); so, when you first create it, you should make sure that it is retained; later, you release it in `dealloc` when you are done with your data source. You retain `myArray` in one of several possible ways, like:

```
 myArray = [[NSArray alloc] init...];
```

in this case, `alloc` already gives you a retained object; or:

```
 myArray = [[NSArray arrayWith...] retain];
```

in this case, you need to retain the object return by the convenience constructor (which returns an autoreleased object);

```
 self.myArray = [NSArray arrayWith...];
```

in this case, you do not need the retain if the `myArray` property is declared as `retain`.

In all of the previous cases, what you do is ensuring that the retain count of the object is at least 1, so that it is not deallocated by the framework at some point. Failing to do so means that at some point in time your object will de automatically deallocated, and this is very likely to happen *before* your data are there, i.e., before `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` is executed.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I found out that methods which returns number of rows and number of sections are called before tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath - just like I wrote in my question...and while my array is not filled with some objects, tableView:NumberOfRowsInSection returns 0 ( [myArray count] ) , so the method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath is not even called... this method is called first time after array is filled with objects......

Comment: ........weird thing is, when I use [[myArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"myKey"] anywhere in the viewcontroller class, everything is ok, but when I use it in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method, app chrashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: I retained the array and now it works...but I dont understand well why it doesnt work without that...could you please explain? Thanks